# JSON Dependency not working in Maven pom.xml

Tags: json, rest, maven, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

i am working on JAX-RS with Jersey, i have  a resource class that return data to the client, i am able to return xml data as responce, but it's not working when i am trying to return JSON,  i got the below ERROR

[image]

something wrong with my POM.xml?

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.amdocs.login.login</groupId>
    <artifactId>login</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>login</name>

    <build>
        <finalName>login</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

     <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <!-- use the following artifactId if you don't need servlet 2.x compatibility -->
            <!-- artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <jersey.version>2.16</jersey.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Comment: What happens if you switch to Jackson? `jersey-media-json-jackson` (replace `jersey-media-moxy`)?

Comment: i replaced it with jersey-media-json-jackson, but still getting the same issue

Comment: Is there any eclipse log that says the actual reason why it can't read from .m2? Do you have any other problem with Maven projects in Eclipse? I wonder if maybe it's a permissions problem. I don't think I've ever seen that error before.

Comment: Glassfish should be a complete EE container, thus embarking all your needed dependencies for a REST service. You should declare them in your pom as "provided"

Answer (score 1):

```
 <dependency>
   <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
   <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
   <version>2.22</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you guys, i found the problem, this issue happened cause i worked with old jersey version, i just changed the version value from 2.16 to 2.22, and run Maven>update project, now it's working fine.